# Trusted Certificate and Key Store generation

Tags: certificate, keystore

Please in my project i want for each ECDSA KeyPair, generate a (Self Signed) trusted certicate of the public key and store it in a keystore. I already geerate the keypair with boundy castle and now want to generate certificate and store ito keystore.

Please how can i do it? Some One has a tutorial than can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can look into the Bouncy Castle documentation [here](http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/X.509+Public+Key+Certificate+and+Certification+Request+Generation) to create certificates. In your use case you should look into the **Creating a version 3 certificate**.

And to store the certificate in a [KeyStore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html#setCertificateEntry(java.lang.String,%20java.security.cert.Certificate)), you can use

```
keyStore.setCertificateEntry(alias, signedCertificate);
```